# creating a variable within tf.variable_scope(name), initialized from another variable's initialized_value

Tags: tensorflow

Hey tensorflow community,

I am experiencing unexpected naming conventions when using variable_scope in the following setup:

```
with tf.variable_scope("my_scope"):
    var = tf.Variable(initial_value=other_var.initialized_value())
```

In the above, it holds that

```
other_var.name = 'outer_scope/my_scope/other_var_name:0'
```

I am therefore "reusing" the same scope at this point in the code. Intuitively I do not see an issue with this, but the following happens:

```
var.name = 'outer_scope/my_scope_1/var_name:0'
```

So apparently, tf isn't happy with "my_scope" and needs to append the "_1". 
The "outer_scope" remains the same, though.

If I do not initialize with "other_var", this behaviour does not come up.

An explanation would be much appreciated! Thx

Mat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to use `tf.get_variable()` instead of 'tf.Variable`.

```
with tf.variable_scope('var_scope', reuse=False) as var_scope:
    var = tf.get_variable('var', [1])
    var2 = tf.Variable([1], name='var2')
    print var.name # var_scope/var:0 
    print var2.name # var_scope/var2:0

with tf.variable_scope('var_scope', reuse=True) as var_scope:
    var = tf.get_variable('var', [1])
    var2 = tf.Variable([1], name='var2')
    print var.name # var_scope/var:0 
    print var2.name # var_scope_1/var2:0
```

The reason behind this I think is that in your example, although you have successfully "re-entered" the variable_scope you want, what really affects your variable name is another scope named `name_scope` intead of `variable_scope` as you might guess. From the official document [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#names-of-ops-in-tf-variable-scope) you can see that:

> when we do with tf.variable_scope("name"), this implicitly opens a
>   tf.name_scope("name").

`name_scope` is originally used for managing operation names(such as `add`, `matmul`), because `tf.Variable` is actually an operation and its operation name will be "inherited" by variables created by it, so the name of `name_scope` rather than `variable_scope` is used as prefix.

But if you want to use tf.Variable, you can also directly use `name_scope` in `with` statement:

```
with tf.name_scope('n_scope') as n_scope:
    var = tf.Variable([1], name='var')
    print var.name #n_scope/var_1:0

with tf.name_scope(n_scope) as n_scope:
    var = tf.Variable([1], name='var')
    print var.name #n_scope/var_1:0
```

One thing to pay attention to is that you should pass as argument the scope varible previously captured from a `with` statement when you want to "re-enter" a name scope, rather than using `str` scope name:

```
  with tf.name_scope('n_scope') as n_scope:
      var = tf.Variable([1], name='var')
      print var.name #n_scope/var_1:0

  with tf.name_scope('n_scope') as n_scope:
      var = tf.Variable([1], name='var')
      print var.name #n_scope_1/var_1:0
```

Pay attention to the argument passed to `tf.name_scope`. This behavior is again described in doc string of `name_scope`:

> The name argument will be interpreted as follows:
>
> 1. A string (not ending with ‘/’) will create a new name scope, in which
>      name is appended to the prefix of all operations created in the
>      context. If name has been used before, it will be made unique by
>      calling self.unique_name(name).
> 2. A scope previously captured from a with g.name_scope(...) as 
>      scope: statement will be treated as an “absolute” name scope, 
>      which makes it possible to re-enter existing scopes.
> 3. A value of None or the empty string will reset the current name 
>      scope to the top-level (empty) name scope.